# how to connect to an MsAccess (accdb) in icCube?

Tags: iccube, ms-access-2016

In icCube 6.1 I want to connect to a MsAccess file stored locally on the icCube server. When I try to connect I get the error message:

> Failed to establish the connection due to the error: JDBC driver class
>   'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver' not found in the classpath

This is what I provide in the connection:

- Name : Clients
- Visibility :
- Driver Type : Access (JDK JDBC/ODBC Bridge)
- Server Name : localhost
- Port Number :
- DB Name : C:\data\Clients.accdb
- User :
- Password :

When I Google on this error I get the message (dated from 2015) that:

> in JDK 8, jdbc odbc bridge is no longer used and thus removed from the
>   JDK.

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you cannot use anymore the JDBC ODBC bridge from JRE 8.

As an alternative you can use a MS Access JDBC driver. For example: [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/). To install this driver in icCube unzip the file and copy the following files into the /lib directory of the icCube install directory:

```
ucanaccess-4.0.2.jar
jackcess-2.1.6.jar
hsqldb.jar
```

Then in the builder data source, select a generic JDBC driver and configure the Server Name and DB Name as following:

```
> Server Name : net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver 
> DB Name     : jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/your-file.accdb
```

[image: UCanAccess Data Source]

Hope that helps.

[edit] Depending on how icCube is started you might need to update the CLASSPATH with the three new JARs. To avoid CLASSPATH edition, you can use the following in the icCube.sh for example to start icCube using all the JARs in the /lib directory:

```
> $JAVA $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$ICCUBE/lib/*" crazydev.iccube.server.IcCubeServer
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and I got the error "JDBC driver class 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver ' not found in the classpath". Do I need to set something in the icCube.xml configuration file?

Comment: How do you start the icCube server? If you are defining the CLASSPATH by adding each JAR you need to update it with the 3 new JAR and restart icCube. I've edited the response.

Comment: I use the icCube.ini file but the default setting is already ok. I retested it and now it works. May be an additional restart did the trick. Thanks.